# как правильно сделать код парсера для python

Tags: python, парсер, requests, bs4

я написал небольшой парсер, но не могу понять как сделать парсер названия фильмов. Вот сам код:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

href_film = {}
count = 0
page = int( input('сколько страниц нужно спарсить: '))
page += 1
page_list = 0
while page_list < page:
    url = 'https://lordserial.live/anime-serialy/' + 'page/' + str(page_list) + '/'
    req = requests.get(url, headers=header)
    soup = bs(req.text, 'lxml')

    kart_film = soup.find_all('div', class_='th-item')
    film_text = soup.find_all('div', class_='th-title')

    for items in kart_film:
        film_text = i.text
        film_href = f'''{items.a['href']}'''
        href_film[count] = film_text,film_href
        
        count += 1

    page_list += 1

with open('herf_film.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    json.dump(href_film, file, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)
```

Comment: `kart_film = ` и `film_text = ` вот тут уже странно выглядит... Если перебираете список с внутренними полями, то нужно в цикле перебирать элементы списка, а в итерациях цикла ходить по внутренним полям. У самих методов элементов тоже есть поисковые функции типа find_all. Ссылку удобнее формировать через форматирование строк: `url = f'https://lordserial.live/anime-serialy/page/{page_list}/'`. `film_href = f'''{items.a['href']}'''` это бессмысленно, т.к. значения атрибутов и так строки, поэтому просто `film_href = items.a['href']`. Я бы посмотрел тот сайт и накидал парсер, но пока на работе :)

Comment: спасибо за объяснение!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Переписал парсер из вопроса, сохранив логику:

- Использование сессии (умеет хранить куки, общие заголовки)
- Использование парсера `html.parser` - он есть из коробки, в отличии от `lxml`
- Использование css-селекторов, это методы `select` и `select_one`. У css-селекторов очень лаконичный синтаксис
- Немного подправил способ составления ссылки, чтобы выглядело естественнее
- Добавлена проверка на плохие статусы HTTP через `raise_for_status`
- Формат записей в виде списка, я думаю удобнее, чем словарем

Пример:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

BASE_URL = 'https://lordserial.live/anime-serialy/'

session = requests.Session()
session.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:100.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/100.0'

items = []
max_page = 5
for page in range(1, max_page + 1):
    url = f'{BASE_URL}/page/{page}/' if page > 1 else BASE_URL
    print(url)

    rs = session.get(url)
    rs.raise_for_status()

    soup = bs(rs.content, 'html.parser')
    for item in soup.select('.th-item'):
        title = item.select_one('.th-title').text
        url = item.a['href']
        items.append({
            'title': title,
            'url': url,
        })

with open('anime-serialy.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    json.dump(items, f, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)
```

Пример результата:

```json
[
    {
        "title": "Семья шпиона",
        "url": "https://lordserial.live/anime-serialy/6114-semya-shpiona.html"
    },
    {
        "title": "Клинок, рассекающий демонов",
        "url": "https://lordserial.live/anime-serialy/1483-klinok-rassekayuwij-demonov.html"
    },
    {
        "title": "Реинкарнация безработного",
        "url": "https://lordserial.live/anime-serialy/5585-reinkarnaciya-bezrabotnogo.html"
    },
    {
        "title": "Суперзлодеи",
        "url": "https://lordserial.live/anime-serialy/5981-superzlodei.html"
    },
    {
        "title": "Звёздные войны: Видение",
        "url": "https://lordserial.live/anime-serialy/5903-zvezdnye-voyny-videnie.html"
    },
    {
        "title": "Повесть о конце света",
        "url": "https://lordserial.live/anime-serialy/5877-povest-o-konce-sveta.html"
    },
...
```

Comment: А как добавить идентификатор в виде цифры, чтоб допустим в другой программе открыть этот список и вывести определенный фильм по цифре?

Comment: @GorkiiOgurec, там же список, поэтому, вы и так сможете получить индекс элемента: 0 - первый фильм, 1 - второй фильм и т.д. Если нужно явно хранить, тогда заводите счетчик и добавляете его в сам словарь с фильмами, либо вместо списка используйте словарь (как уже вы делали в вопросе), где ключом будет тот счетчик (но мне кажется это не очень). Или вы про номера фильмов, что я заметил в ссылках: 6114, 1483, 5585 и т.д.?

Comment: А хорошо, тогда по индексу определять буду. Спасибо за подробное объяснение!

Answer (score 1):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

href_film = []
url_p = 'https://lordserial.live/anime-serialy/'
while True:
    req = requests.get(url_p)
    soup = bs(req.text, 'lxml')

    for q in soup.findAll('div', class_='th-item'):
        title = q.find('div', class_='th-title').text
        year = q.find('div', class_='th-year').text
        url = q.a['href']
        href_film.append({'title': title, 'year': year, 'url': url})
    try:
        url_p = soup.find('div', id='pagi-load').a['href']
    except Exception:
        break
print(href_film)

[{'title': 'Семья шпиона', 'year': '(2022)', 'url': 'https://lordserial.live/anime-serialy/6114-semya-shpiona.html'}, {'title': 'Клинок, рассекающий демонов', 'year': '(2019)', 'url': 'https://lordserial.live/anime-serialy/1483-klinok-rassekayuwij-demonov.html'}, .... {'title': 'Боруто: Новое поколение Наруто', 'year': '(2017)', 'url': 'https://lordserial.live/anime-serialy/1466-boruto--novoe-pokolenie-naruto-1-seasone.html'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот ещё вариант:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep

headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) 
            AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)"
            " Chrome/101.0.4951.67 Safari/537.36"}

page = int( input('сколько страниц нужно спарсить: '))

def card_film():
    for page_num in range(0, page):
        URL = f'https://lordserial.live/anime-serialy/page/{page_num}/'
        response = requests.get(URL, headers=headers).text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'lxml')
        card = soup.find_all('div', class_='th-item')

        for data in card:
            name = data.find('div', class_='th-title').text
            card_url = data.find('a', class_='th-in with-mask').get('href')
            yield name, card_url

items = []

for title, url in card_film():
    sleep(1)
    items.append({'title': title, 'url': url,})
```

Это, если нужно оставить запрос на количество страниц. И не просто циклами прогонять а в функцию-генератор обернуть. Если большой объём данных будет, то при таком подходе не нужно всё это в памяти держать. Будет выдёргивать по одной паре и потом записывать. Ну и интервалы между запросами лучше ставить, так, как минимум,нагрузка на сайт меньше.

Вот результат, с одной страницы:

```
items = [
{'title': 'Семья шпиона', 'url': 'https://lordserial.live/anime-serialy/6114-semya-shpiona.html'},
 {'title': 'Клинок, рассекающий демонов', 'url': 'https://lordserial.live/anime-serialy/1483-klinok-rassekayuwij-demonov.html'},
 {'title': 'Реинкарнация безработного', 'url': 'https://lordserial.live/anime-serialy/5585-reinkarnaciya-bezrabotnogo.html'},
 {'title': 'Суперзлодеи', 'url': 'https://lordserial.live/anime-serialy/5981-superzlodei.html'},
 {'title': 'Звёздные войны: Видение', 'url': 'https://lordserial.live/anime-serialy/5903-zvezdnye-voyny-videnie.html'},
 {'title': 'Повесть о конце света', 'url': 'https://lordserial.live/anime-serialy/5877-povest-o-konce-sveta.html'},
 {'title': 'Клеймор', 'url': 'https://lordserial.live/anime-serialy/5874-kleymor.html'},
 {'title': 'Убить или быть убитым', 'url': 'https://lordserial.live/anime-serialy/5873-ubit-ili-byt-ubitym.html'},
 {'title': 'Да, я паук, и что с того?', 'url': 'https://lordserial.live/anime-serialy/5858-da-ya-pauk-i-chto-s-togo.html'},
 {'title': 'Избранный богами', 'url': 'https://lordserial.live/anime-serialy/5857-izbrannyy-bogami.html'},
 {'title': 'Властелины вселенной: Откровение', 'url': 'https://lordserial.live/anime-serialy/5852-vlasteliny-vselennoy-otkrovenie.html'},
 {'title': 'Инцидент Кэмоно', 'url': 'https://lordserial.live/anime-serialy/5828-incident-kemono.html'},
 {'title': 'Тресе: Защитница города', 'url': 'https://lordserial.live/anime-serialy/5794-trese-zashchitnica-goroda.html'},
 {'title': 'Эдем', 'url': 'https://lordserial.live/anime-serialy/5787-edem.html'},
 {'title': 'Путь домохозяина', 'url': 'https://lordserial.live/anime-serialy/5783-put-domohozyaina.html'},
 {'title': 'Темный дворецкий 2', 'url': 'https://lordserial.live/anime-serialy/5781-temnyy-dvoreckiy-2.html'},
 {'title': 'Темный дворецкий', 'url': 'https://lordserial.live/anime-serialy/5782-temnyy-dvoreckiy.html'},
 {'title': 'Ясукэ', 'url': 'https://lordserial.live/anime-serialy/5733-yasuke.html'}
]
```