# Делаю парсер hh ,но мой парсер собирает не все ссылки на странице

Tags: python, beautiful-soup, re

Делаю парсер hh на Python.На странице hh находится 50 карточек ,я пытаюсь получить все 50 ссылок на них,но при выполнении моей программы я получаю только 20 ссылок из 50.Может новые карточки подгружаются динамически,хотя в коде элемента присутствуют все 50 карточек.Кто может сказать в чем дело?

```
def pars3():
    url='https://ekaterinburg.hh.ru/search/vacancy?area=3&clusters=true&enable_snippets=true&ored_clusters=true&text=Python&search_period=7&hhtmFrom=vacancy_search_list'
    head={'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.159 Safari/537.36'}
    respons=requests.get(url,headers=head)
    src=respons.text

   
    m=[]
 
    soup=BeautifulSoup(src,'html.parser')
    zapros=soup.find_all('div',class_='vacancy-serp-item')
    for i in zapros:
        a=i.find_all('a',class_='bloko-link')
        for z in a:
            if z['href'][0]=='h' and z['href']!='https://feedback.hh.ru/article/details/id/5951':
                m.append(z['href'])



    return m
```

Как сделать так чтобы парсер стянул всю информацию с сайта ??

Answer (score 0):

По вопросу не совсем понятно, какую именно информацию Вам нужно вытянуть с сайта. Можно сделать следующим образом:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep


headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.159 Safari/537.36'}


list = []

for page in range(1, 3):
    url = f'https://ekaterinburg.hh.ru/search/vacancy?area=3&clusters=true&enable_snippets=true&ored_clusters=true&text=Python&search_period=7&page={page}&hhtmFrom=vacancy_search_list'
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r, 'lxml')
    card=soup.find_all('div',class_='vacancy-serp-item')
    for url in card:
        sleep(1)
        card_url = url.find('a', class_='bloko-link').get('href')
        list.append(card_url)
```

Получаем ссылки на каждую карточку, и записываем их в список. После этого проходимся ещё одним циклом. Но там нужно опять делать запрос, уже на полученные ссылки. И из карточки вытягивайте уже нужную вам информацию.

```
for data in list:
   sleep(1)
   r1 = requests.get(data, headers=headers).text
   soup = BeautifulSoup(r1, 'lxml')
```

Ну и, чтобы не нагружать сайт и оптимизировать работу программы, не держать все данные в памяти в процессе обработки, можно сделать функцию-генератор. Примерно как здесь: [как правильно сделать код парсера для python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1418906/%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-python/1419045#1419045)

Comment: На сайте находится 50 вакансий ,я хочу забрать 50 ссылок на них.А получаю только 20.

Comment: И при выполнении вашего кода я получаю 20 ссылок а не все

Comment: @Miha согласен есть недочёт. Поменяйте диапазон в цикле. Начните с числа"0". Попробовал, получил 60 ссылок.

Comment: но 60 ссылок это тоже не верно,на каждой странице 50 карточек.Если цикл с 0 до 3 получается 3 страницы и ссылок должно быть 150.Видимо на сайте новые карточки подгружаются динамически или есть какой то запрет ,чего я понять не могу.Может вы знаете?

Comment: К сожалению не подскажу, нет нужного опыта и знаний. Сам только учусь.